# How can I open multiple URLs in a new Chrome window from the terminal

Tags: terminal, google-chrome

I can open multiple URLs in the current Chrome window from the terminal:

```
open https://www.apple.com/ https://www.apple.com/ https://www.amazon.com/
```

When I tried to open them in a new window using

```
open -n https://www.apple.com/ https://www.apple.com/ https://www.amazon.com/
```

Chrome responds with only a blank new window.

How can I open all of the URLs in a new window?

Answer (score 2):

### The lazy solution

Use AppleScript to make the new window, then use `open` without the `-n`:

```
osascript -e 'tell app id "com.google.chrome" to make new window' \
  && open https://www.apple.com/ https://www.apple.com/ https://www.amazon.com/
```

As soon as the window has opened, chances are that Chrome will use it for all the URLs.
However, that solution is **prone to race conditions,** especially if another window is created or activated while your command runs.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>[1] In practice, there are several scenarios where this can happen, e. g. if you run your command in parallel, or if Chrome tries to recover its windows after a crash, or when the user (or another program) attempts to open a new window, etc.</sup>

### The more robust solution

A more robust alternative, which does not have the race condition mentioned above, is the following all-AppleScript solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
on run(theUrls)
    tell app id "com.google.chrome" to tell make new window
            repeat with theUrl in theUrls
                set newTab to make new tab with properties { url: theUrl }
            end repeat
            tell tab 1 to close
    end tell
end run
```

Save that code, preferably as a file without extension (e. g. `open_new_window`). Place that file somewhere into your `PATH`. Make sure to `chmod 755` the script so it’s executable. For good measure, I’d recommend to also `sudo chmod root:wheel` it.

From now on, you can invoke the script like so:

```
open_new_window https://www.apple.com/ https://www.apple.com/ https://www.amazon.com/
```

### In case you don’t want to use a separate script

Use the following variant for testing, or if you prefer a command line without a separate script:

```
osascript \
  -e 'on run(theUrls)' \
  -e '  tell app id "com.google.chrome" to tell make new window' \
  -e '    repeat with theUrl in theUrls' \
  -e '      set newTab to make new tab ¬' \
  -e '        with properties { url: theUrl }' \
  -e '    end repeat' \
  -e '    tell tab 1 to close' \
  -e '  end tell' \
  -e 'end run' \
  https://www.apple.com/ https://www.apple.com/ https://www.amazon.com/
```